# Cannot convert from void to System.Action when trying to call a method

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
    public void UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol(DconF dconF)
    {
        var allDconf = GetDConfFromCol();           
        allDconf[dconF.id.ToString()] = dconF;          
        var serializeJson = Helpers.JsonConverter.SerializeEscapeHtml(allDconf);
        App.CM.UpdateCol(serializeJson,CONST.dconfCol);
    }
```

I would like to time how long it takes to execute so I am trying to use some code that my application has:

```
public static partial class Helper
{
    public static string Timer(Action action)
    {
        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        stopWatch.Start();
        action();
        return stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    }

    public static int TimerInt(Action action)
    {
        var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        stopWatch.Start();
        action();
        return (int) stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Here is where I am using it:

```
var abc = Helper.Timer(App.CM.UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol(App.CM.SelectedDconf));
```

But it gives me an error message saying:

```
argument 1, cannot convert from void to system Action
```

Comment: FYI, `StartNew` creates a new stopwatch and then starts it. You don't have to call `Start` afterwards. However you'd normally call `Stop` before returning the elapsed time.

Comment: Because `UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol` returns `void` which means your code becomes this: `var abc = Helper.Timer(void);`, But the `Timer` method expects an Action and hence you get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in `App.CM.UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol(App.CM.SelectedDconf)` to the `Helper.Timer`. That returns void and gets evaluated to be a parameter to `Helper.Timer` method. However, `Helper.Timer` expects an action. This is the reason for the error you are seeing.

You may do the following

```
// Pass the action as a parameter and invoke this inside the method with the parameter
// The action in this case should be Action<T> where T is DConf
var abc = Helper.Timer(App.CM.UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol);

// invoking the action with the parameter within Helper.Timer
// However, the helper needs to know of the parameter App.CM.UpdateConf separately. Another
// simpler alternative is provided in the second approach below
action(App.CM.UpdateConf);
```

OR

Always, in general, make sure to pass the delegate (`Action` in this case) as shown below and do not pass call to the method directly as that gets evaluated to the return type of the method but not as a delegate as we expect it to be.

```
var abc = Helper.Timer(() => App.CM.UpdateDConfDictionaryToCol(App.CM.SelectedDconf))
```